# ant nesting macro call

Tags: ant, macrodef

I would like to call a macro from inside an element of another macro.
Let's suppose I have the following macro:

```
<macrodef name="jc">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="destdir" />
    <element name="fileset-list" optional="false" />
    <sequential>
        <jar destfile="@{destdir}${file.separator}@{name}.jar" update="false">
            <fileset-list />
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Manifest-Version" value="1.0" />       
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

and another macro

```
<macrodef name="defaultfs" description="Defines the default fileset">
    <attribute name="path" />
    <sequential>
        <fileset dir="${dir.build.classes}">
            <include name="@{path}/**/*.class" />
        </fileset>
        <fileset dir="${src.ehs}">
            <include name="@{path}/**/icons/**" />
            <include name="@{path}/**/sounds/**" />
            <include name="@{path}/**/*.gif" />
            <include name="@{path}/**/*.png" />
            <include name="@{path}/**/*.wav" />
            <include name="@{path}/**/*.jpg" />
            <include name="@{path}/**/*.properties" />
            <include name="@{path}/**/*.xml" />
            <include name="@{path}/**/jaxb.index" />
        </fileset>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

I use these macros as follow:

```
<jc destdir="${dir.build.jar}" name="thejar">
    <fileset-list>
        <defaultfs path="org/path/inner" />
    </fileset-list>
</jc>
```

What I get is the following error message:

```
jar doesn't support the nested "defaultfs" element.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The "jar" ANT task has not been written to support a "defaultfs" XML element. Macros in ANT are something different, they act more like templates.

Comment: you are right, but my requirement is to use jc in a broader way, and I have some jar that are build with a similar fileset.
Are the macros evaluated only once?

Comment: I have a similar case, where I want to use a macro inside an (implicit) element parameter to a macro. Haven't yet figured out how to -- or if it's possible to -- get the inner macro evaluated before the outer macro. If you can find an answer to this, I'm definitely interested! (And no, combining the two macros isn't an answer -- I want each of these to act independently as if it was a normal Ant task, without users having to be aware that they're macros.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try making macro call within your main macro 'jc' and pass fileset path to consider as an additional attribute

```
<macrodef name="jc">
    <attribute name="name" />
    <attribute name="destdir" />
    <attribute name="fileset.path.to.consider" />
    <sequential>
        <jar destfile="@{destdir}${file.separator}@{name}.jar" update="false">
            <defaultfs path="@{fileset.path.to.consider}"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Manifest-Version" value="1.0" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

And then your main macro call could look like :

```
<jc destdir="${dir.build.jar}" name="thejar" fileset.path.to.consider="org/path/inner"/>
```

(not tested, you could give it a try )

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't what I want.